# How can I share cookies between two subdomains of herokuapp.com?

Tags: heroku, cookies, cross-domain, samesite

I am currently trying to host a website as an experiment on Heroku, I deployed the back end which you can consider `yyyy.herokuapp.com` and the front end with you can consider `xxxx.herokuapp.com`,

Now, here's the issue, I need to set cookies between `xxxx` and `yyyy`, I know this will be a massive security issue but since this is an experimental website I am not willing to get a custom domain, I tried to set the cookies' domain to: `herokuapp.com`, `.herokuapp.com`, `*.herokuapp.com`, `xxxx.herokuapp.com`, `yyyy.herokuapp.com`.

Yet it doesn't work, chrome denies the cookies and gives this message:

> This attempt to set a cookie via a Set-Cookie header was blocked because its Domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url.

So, how do I approach this issue without the need for a custom domain?
this is my configuration to set cookies (on the back end which uses flask)

```py
response.set_cookie("example_cookie", value="cookie value", 
    max_age=900, expires=datetime.datetime.utcnow() + 
    datetime.timedelta(seconds=900), secure=True, domain=".herokuapp.com", 
    samesite='none')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `herokuapp.com` were not a *public suffix* (a.k.a. an *effective top-level domain* or *eTLD*), then in the case of a cookie set by `xxxx.herokuapp.com` with `Domain=herokuapp.com`, browsers would send that cookie to `yyyy.herokuapp.com`

However, there is a snag: in order to isolate its different tenants, Heroku required [`herokuapp.com` be added to the public-suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat) a while back. Most browsers [refuse to set a cookie for a public suffix](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-03.html#rfc.section.4.1.2.3):

> For security reasons, many user agents are configured to reject Domain attributes that correspond to “public suffixes”. For example, some user agents will reject Domain attributes of “com” or “co.uk”.

Therefore, attempts to set a cookie with `Domain=herokuapp.com` will be rejected by browsers, as you've experienced.

---

Note: adding a leading dot in the `Domain` attribute of the `Set-Cookie` HTTP header has no effect, at least in modern browsers.

---

To get out of this difficulty, you could simply buy a cheap domain name (say `infinityvive.com`) to serve both your frontend and backend from subdomains of it. Then you'd be able to use `Domain=infinityvive.com` because your domain would not be a public suffix.