# Cookie is not saved in cookie tab under application tab of the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, mern

response header: to login request in this cookie is coming but its not saving cookie tab under application tab so when other protected routes API are called cookie is not available to req.cookie in backend.

```js
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
cf-ray: 78a4701cbacde632-DEL
content-encoding: br
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Mon, 16 Jan 2023 05:26:45 GMT
etag: W/"b6-G5852pWMZyQUZxU70pjkK7l2Nuw"
server: cloudflare
set-cookie: token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2M2M0MDI5MWNlYWVmY2JjZmY5NmUwNTYiLCJpYXQiOjE2NzM4NDY4MDUsImV4cCI6MTY3NTE0MjgwNX0.0jnuEWUQBGwlSTRhNXBxaL-2L0aIXIHPEavuj3RCHYE; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 16 Jan 2023 20:26:45 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-powered-by: Express
```

screenshot of the application tab with no cookie saved
[image: screenshot of the application tab]

now if I called other protected routes it's giving me 400 errors as in the backend it's checking if a user is logged in using the cookie.

request failed as no cookie is saved so authentication failed
[image: request failed as no cookie is saved so authentication failed]

frontend axios call:

```js
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk('user/loginUser', async (user, thunkAPI) =>{
    try {
        const resp = await customFetch.post("/auth/login", user, {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
              },
              withCredentials: true
            });
        return resp.data;
    } catch (error) {
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data.msg);
    }
});


import axios from "axios";
// import {getLocalStorageUser}  from "./localStorage";
const customFetch = axios.create({
    baseURL:"https://jobster-server.onrender.com/api/v1/",
});
```

env variables

```
PORT=4000
JWT_SECRET=*************************************
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://deepanshu:********@cluster0.til7lwc.mongodb.net/jobsterre?retryWrites=true
FRONTEND_URI=http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

app.js

```js
import express from "express";
import { config } from "dotenv";
import { ErrorMiddleWare } from "./middleWares/Error.js";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import cors from "cors";

config({
    path:"./config/config.env"
})
const app =express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(
    express.urlencoded({
        extended:true
    })
)
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({
    origin:process.env.FRONTEND_URI,
    credentials:true,
    methods:["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"]
}))
import user from "./routes/userRoutes.js";
import job from "./routes/jobRoutes.js";
app.use("/api/v1", user);
app.use("/api/v1", job);

app.get("/", (req,res) =>{
    res.send(`Site is working, Click <a href=${process.env.FRONTEND_URI}>here</a> to visit frontend`);
})
app.use(ErrorMiddleWare);
export default app;
```

login function backend

```js
export const loginUser = catchAsyncError(async (req, res, next) =>{
    const {email, password} = req.body;
    if(!email || !password){
        return next(new ErrorHandler(400, "Please fill all the fields"));
    }
    let user = await User.findOne({email}).select("+password");
    if(!user){
        return next(new ErrorHandler(404, "email or password is not correct"));
    }
    const isPasswordMatched = await user.comparePassword(password);
    if(!isPasswordMatched){
        return next(new ErrorHandler(404, "email or password is not correct"));
    }
    user.password = undefined;
    sendToken(res, user, `Welcome back ${user.name}`,200);
})


export const sendToken=(res, user, message, statusCode)=>{
    const token = user.getJwtToken();
    const options = {
        httpOnly:true,
        sameSite:"None",
        expires:new Date(Date.now() + 15*60*60*1000),
        secure:true,
    }
    res.status(statusCode).cookie("token", token, options).json({
        success:true,
        message,
        user
    })
}



export const catchAsyncError = (passedFunction) => (req, res, next) =>{
    Promise.resolve(passedFunction(req,res,next)).catch(next);
}
```

Comment: Your domain is in [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat). It means that borwser doesn't allow you to set cookies on subdomains of this domain (for security purposes). To solve this problem buy a cheap domain. [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68688890/how-can-i-share-cookies-between-two-subdomains-of-herokuapp-com)

Comment: It not working on localhost also. So, is there any way to do so in localHost as I don't want to buy a domain for my experimental projects

Comment: try to add path:"/" property in options, I think it would help

Comment: that is already coming in set-cookie

Answer (score 0):

I also have issue but my issue is resolve now. I think your above code is correct there is case of minor mistake in when you call protected route you should also set
credentials: 'include' in fetch
withCredentials: true in axios

if you not set credentials than devtools will not show token cookie, So set credentials then request your protected route then it will automatically show in you devtools.